# python3 - format with {} symbols

Tags: python-3.x

I hav egot problem with string

```
'replication = {\'class\' : \'NetworkTopologyStrategy\', \'datacenter1\' : {}};'.format(N)
```

Why does it return:

```
replication = \{\'class\' : \'NetworkTopologyStrategy\', \'datacenter1\': {} };'.format(N)  
KeyError: "'class' "
```

Comment: If you notice, you're not actually escaping your characters.

Comment: Literal `{` and `}` characters in a format string must be escaped: `{{` `}}`

Answer (score 1):

Formatting a string that contains arbitrary `{}` can be funky.

In this case you'd need to surround the entire string in additional `{}` in order to escape the `{` and `}` that should be ignored by `format`:

```
N = 'xxx'
print('replication = {{\'class\' : \'NetworkTopologyStrategy\', \'datacenter1\' : {}}};'
      .format(N))

# replication = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : xxx};
```

Comment: Thank you. I have solve it by 'replication = {\'class\' : \'NetworkTopologyStrategy\', \'' + data_center_name + '\' : ' + str(N) + ' }'. But your way is more pretty